# How to create a list of N numbers in Python from the given fixed geometric series?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a fixed geometric series numbers ranging from 1 to 64 `(1,2,4,8,16,32,64)`, and I need to create a random list of `N` numbers from them - with repetition in equal proportion of each number and another list with unequal proportion.

What should I do to create a list of `N` numbers from this first? I have written the below code till now - considering `N = 21`.

```
# When N = 21
import random

population = [1,1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,8,8,8,16,16,16,32,32,32,64,64,64]


def sample_wr(population, k):
    # "Chooses k random elements (with replacement) from a population"

    n = len(population)
    _random, _int = random.random, int  # speed hack 
        result = [None] * k
        for i in xrange(k):
            j = _int(_random() * n)
            result[i] = population[j]
        return result


Random_Sample = sample_wr(population, 21)
print(Random_Sample)
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you expect from "unequal proportion"?  Does "equal proportion" *demand* that the numbers be evenly distributed, or only that you *expect* that overall?  What's wrong with the current output?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simplify your "proportional representation" code to

```
from random import choice

def sample_wr(population, k):
    return [choice(population) for _ in range(k)]
```

If you want unequal proportions, you will have to define just what proportions you *do* want.

Answer (score 0):

For the first, I would use `shuffle`.

```
def balancedsample(population, k):
    population = (population * math.ceil(k/len(population)))[:k]
    random.shuffle(population)
    return population
```

This simply multiplies the population list as many times as necessary to get enough elements, truncates in case `k` isn't a perfect multiple of `len(population)`, and shuffles the result.

For the second, I would do it the way [Hugh suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35143259/789671).